# How to get all instances of a given class in another module

Tags: python, oop

So I'm not sure if this question was answered elsewhere but I couldn't find any viable solution specifically relevant to this case as they were either how to access the instances in the same file (which works fine) or using reload() (which didn't work).

I've got two python files, module1.py and module2.py. In module1.py there's a class with a bunch of instances that I need to access from module2.
I append each instance to a list (as a class variable) on instantiation but when importing module1, the instances haven't been instantiated so this list is empty. This means I can access this list of instances in module1 but in module2 it is empty.

module1.py

```
class Class1:
  instances = [ ]
  def __init__(self):
    self.instances.append(self)

a = Class1()
b = Class1()
c = Class1()
```

module2.py

```
import module1
def foo():
  print(len(module1.Class1.instances))
  #prints zero, list should not be empty
```

So how can I access these instances which are created in module1 from module2?

Comment: The shown code should actually fail. Use `module1.Class1.instances`.

Comment: Also, there is nowhere in the code you show where instances get created.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille The instances get created in module1. Didn't think it was relevant

Comment: @MichaelButscher I meant that, my mistake

Comment: And you're sure that the code that creates them gets executed?

Comment: @OmGal It's absolutely relevant, because right now, without any evidence that you are *are* creating any instances, a perfectly reasonable answer is that you are getting the correct output, because the list is indeed empty. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Right sorry. Yes I'm sure those instances get created. As I mentioned in my original post, the list in module1 contains all the instances.

Comment: What version of python are you using? It works fine if you call foo() in module2 in your exact code above. Py 3.8.2

Comment: @OUR python 3.6

Comment: I conclude that the problem is outside of the shown code. You can try to copy the code shown in your question to a new folder and try to run it from there. If it works as expected, find the difference to the real code. If it doesn't work, something in the execution environment (IDE configuration, sys.path,...) is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do instead, is call the Class you're importing, so either import using [* (Import all)][1] or import specific classes as so:

```
from module1 import *
def foo():
    return Class1.instances
c = foo()[0]
print(type(c)) # Is of type Module1.Class1
```

and In module1:

```
class Class1:
   instances = []
   def __init__(self):
       self.instances.append(self)


a = Class1()
b = Class1()
```

Now instances has 2 elements, and you can access them in module2

Comment: @OmGal Your question is not understandable, you need to create a foo() instance to print the instances of Class1

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include creating the instances in the post.

Comment: @OmGal It works fine to me, does it work to you too? maybe because your program is larger something collides with this code so I can't tell why it does not work for you, it is a valid python code

Comment: It looks like this should work but I still end up with an empty list

Answer (score 1):

See the module1.py below:

```
class Class1:
  instances = [ ]
  def __init__(self):
    self.instances.append(self)

cls = Class1()
print(Class1.instances)
```

Only if you create an object then would that be added to the instances[] list. since you didn't create an object, the list was empty.

And in the module2.py:

```
import module1
def foo():
  print(len(module1.Class1.instances))
foo()
```

The instances list belongs to the class so you need to give like `module1.Class1.instances`

The output is like below:
After running both the files :

```
[<module1.Class1 object at 0x00000278A447CB70>]
1
```